# Get {count} for a Relationships field within a Grid field

Tags: relationships, grid

How do I get count for this scenario? Each row returns "1":

```
{grid_field}
  {grid_field:relationships_field}
    {grid_field:relationships_field:count}
      // incorrectly shows 1 for each row
  {/grid_field:relationships_field}
{/grid_field}
```

Count works fine for the grid field.

EE 2.10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is right. You need to pass relationships field with grid prefix like this:

```
{grid_field}
  {grid_field:relationships_field}
    {grid_field:relationships_field:count}
      // incorrectly shows 1 for each row
  {/grid_field:relationships_field}
{/grid_field}
```

Comment: You beat me to posting by a minute.

Comment: Next time mate :)

Comment: My apologies, I made a mistake in the question. I have in fact passed the relationships field with a grid prefix (I am successfully pulling data from the related entry but cannot get count). Question updated.

Comment: Now it's working... Must be one of those days - no idea what the problem was, but I'll mark your answer as accepted anyway as it is the correct syntax.